# How to reach out edge optmized Api Gateway from an EC2 with private link?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I would like to reach out my API Gateway (edge optimized) from an EC2 without an internet connection. It is possible?
I have attached a private link from my EC2 VPC to API Gateway and I'm able to resolve my regional  API gateway but not my edge API gateway.. Why?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Your EC2 instance will need access to the public internet (through IGW) to be able to make HTTPS requests and reach any public API (regional or edge-optimized). If your use-case demands the communication to be internal to the VPC (no public internet access), you should consider using [private APIs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/).